# Advanced Testing Setup - Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, minitest

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and my test worked fine until I installed the advanced testing setup at the end on chapter 3. I never got the expected result[image: minitest reporters]

[image: the expected result]

Now when I run a test I receive this message[image: error message from running test]

result when I run rake db:migrate[image: error message from running rake db:migrate]
 Here's a copy of controller[image: static pages controller test]

Comment: You have the exact same test example "should get about" twice, that's what the warning is telling you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's warning you of a duplicate title in your `StaticPagesControllerTest`. The last test is looking for the `contact` page, change it's title to 'Should get contact'.

Then try re-running rake `rake db:migrate`